# Azure Storage Explorer: The server is busy

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with an Azure virtual machine.  The VM won't boot.  So, to at least get our files off of it, I am trying to use Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to download the VM in question.  Unfortunately, even though I can browse to the VM, whenever I attempt to download it the download will start, reach several hundred or so MB, and then fail with the message "Failed to Download ''  The server is busy.".  I am new to Azure, but my boss tells me he has been seeing something similar.

Does anyone else have any experience with Azure Storage Explorer?  Is there a better way to download the VHD?

Between the failure of the VM in the first place, the failure to simply enable diagnostics, and the failure to download the VHD, I am not impressed with Azure!

Comment: How was this question "too broad"?  I had a simple question: 
"Does anyone else have any experience with Azure Storage Explorer? Is there a better way to download the VHD?"
You can tell which bits of my post are the actual question because they end in a question mark (?).

Eventually I did find a link inside the Azure portal and was able to download it from there.  So to answer my original question, Yes there is a better way, find the link on the website in the Storage account section, not the Virtual machines section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain the information off your VHD you do not need to download it on prem.

To get the data please do the following:

1) Create a temp VM located in the same Resource Group and storage account of the broken VM

2) Delete the Broken Virtual Machine

3) Attached the OS disk of the broken VM to the temp VM

4) Copy any data off as needed

Alternatively, could you tell me more about the non-boot VM? Are you getting any specific error upon boot? You can check this on the Boot Diagnostics tab in the Azure Portal. I have a few non-boot scenarios on my blog located here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/

You could always attempt to use Nested Virtualization to recover the VM:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/troubleshoot-a-broken-azure-vm-using-nested-virtualization-in-azure-managed-disk/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/troubleshoot-broken-azure-vm-using-nested-virtualization-in-azure-rdfe/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/troubleshoot-broken-azure-vm-using-nested-virtualization-in-azure-arm/

Comment: also to add, I find the best way of downloading a VHD is to use Azcopy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy

Comment: Thank you Micah!  I'm not sure why you got down-voted, I wish the hater had left a comment

Comment: No worries! Just happy to provide any help I can! :)